# How to refer overriden class functions in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, class-method, static-functions

I know C++ and Java and I am unfamiliar with *Pythonic* programming. So maybe it is bad style what I am trying to do.

Consider fallowing example:

```py
class foo:
        def a():
                __class__.b() # gives: this is foo
                bar.b() # gives: this is bar
                foo.b() # gives: this is foo
                # b() I'd like to get "this is bar" automatically

        def b():
                print("this is foo")

class bar( foo ):
        def b( ):
                print("this is bar")

bar.a()
```

Notice, that I am not using `self` parameters as I am not trying to make instances of classes, as there is no need for my task. I am just trying to refer to a function in a way that the function could be overridden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is for `a` to be a classmethod.

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def a(cls):
        Foo.b() # gives: this is foo
        Bar.b() # gives: this is bar
        cls.b() # gives: this is bar
    @staticmethod
    def b():
        print("this is foo")

class Bar(Foo):
    @staticmethod
    def b():
        print("this is bar")

Bar.a()
```

I've edited your style to match the [Python coding style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Use 4 spaces as your indent. Don't put extra spaces in between parenthesis. Capitalize & CamelCase class names.

A `staticmethod` is a method on a class that doesn't take any arguments and doesn't act on attributes of the class. A `classmethod` is a method on a class that gets the class automatically as an attribute.

Your use of inheritance was fine.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer had also some info I didn't know to ask. Now I know, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python) also gives some useful info about these decorators.

Comment: I'd suggest you read about them on the built in functions page of the docs as well, http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [Execution Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding):

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class
>   block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods – this
>   includes generator expressions since they are implemented using a
>   function scope.

This mean that there is no name `b` in the scope of function `a`.  You should refer to it via class or instance object.

Comment: He didn't know how to do that while still allowing it to be overridden - that was his question.

Comment: @agf I believe he want to know why it is happening.